# Spring Security CORS not working. Getting 403

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I have tried multiple scenarios with the same problem. It returns 401 when http.cors is not in the chain and 403 when I set it as disable or supply my own CorsConfigurationSource. I am calling the endpoint from Angular

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http)throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(r -> r
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .cors(cors->cors.disable());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

[image: This is what the browser tool returns]

Let me know your thoughts. The only thing I haven't tried is changing /** from the config.

EDIT: The difference between this and the duplicate question is that the headers were not explicitly explained in the other response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally got it.

I had started based on the official documentation at:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/integrations/cors.html

One of the things they forgot to mention is that I MUST add
configuration.setAllowedHeaders in the configuration (Thanks DingHao for adding it to your solution).

TLDR; added:

```
configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("content-type"));
```

And it worked.

Long answer:
I created a OncePerRequestFilter and set cors as disabled as stated in the original file. When it is set as disabled, basically it is up to you to handle CORS. So I added in this filter:

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST");
```

And after making the request, dev tools said it needed Access-Control-Allow-Headers. So after some research, I came to know that I must put the headers that are requested here, in my case content-type. So I added

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
```

And Dev tools complained about something, I then switched it (still in the filter with cors disabled) to

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type");
```

(Actually, dev tools was giving me a hint this was missing as preflight worked, but not the POST request). And then POST and preflight worked just fine!

So then, I removed the filter and added the config from the documentation and noticed that @DingHao had that method that the docs were missing. So I changed it to the tested headers and DONE! It worked!

Image of failure message with different header I need to add. Interesting that if this fails, it just fails completely when doing CorsConfig
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add cors support like so

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .cors(c->c.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
            .build();
}

@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:4200"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, this is still showing 403 in Postman and Angular

Comment: Adding '*' did not solve it. I had to add the actual headers that will be sent in the POST request, so, I now get the request from the context, get the headers, set them in a list and then push them in the config. However I think I will change this so no malicious headers are thrown in. I rather keep control of what headers I receive

Comment: If you don't mind, you can provide a minimal demo that reproduces the issue.